# Basic File Browse

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, file, tkinter

Below is a `Browse` class that lets the user browse files and show the path in an entry frame. This is pretty short and basic.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


class Browse(tk.Frame):
    """ Creates a frame that contains a button when clicked lets the user to select
    a file and put its filepath into an entry.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, initialdir='', filetypes=()):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.filepath = tk.StringVar()
        self._initaldir = initialdir
        self._filetypes = filetypes
        self._create_widgets()
        self._display_widgets()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        self._entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.filepath)
        self._button = tk.Button(self, text="Browse...", command=self.browse)

    def _display_widgets(self):
        self._entry.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
        self._button.pack(anchor='se')

    def browse(self):
        """ Browses a .png file or all files and then puts it on the entry.
        """

        self.filepath.set(fd.askopenfilename(initialdir=self._initaldir,
                                             filetypes=self._filetypes))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    file_browser = Browse(root, initialdir=r"C:\Users",
                                filetypes=(('Portable Network Graphics','*.png'),
                                                            ("All files", "*.*")))
    file_browser.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

**Review Concern(s):**

- My main concern is to code in an easy to read, efficient, and well-structured manner while still learning the language and concepts such as OOP. Feel free to mention the tiniest issue or improvement that comes to your mind, as I am a beginner and I probably need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks pretty good.

Personally I wouldn't use a `StringVar`, unless part of the goal was to allow the caller to link this variable to some other widget. Often, the use of `StringVar` just adds another object to keep track of without providing much of a benefit in return, since you can easily set the value of an entry or label widget without it.

I also personally find it a bit easier to define the file types as a variable since it can be cumbersome to squeeze a bunch of file types into the list of parameters. In this case it's not too bad, but you might want to consider doing it like this:

```
filetypes = (
    ('Portable Network Graphics','*.png'),
    ("All files", "*.*")
)
file_browser = Browse(root, initialdir=r"C:\Users",
                      filetypes=filetypes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your review. I actually didn't initially use a `StringVar` too, based on your suggestions in a question. Then I wanted to use it so that if the user manipulated the content of the `entry` with keyboard `self.filename` would be in sync. I thought it would be misguiding to give the user an entry that they can edit and then have no account for that edit.

Comment: That makes sense.